# Transfer Listview Items to listbox in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I would like to transfer the Listview Item and its subitems to a listbox in VB.net.
This is my code, but however it doesnt seem to be working for me. The subitem property fails to popup during typing the syntax. Am I missing something?

```
ListBox1.Items.Add(Item.Text & " " & Item.SubItems(1).Text & " " & Item.SubItems(2).Text)
```

Answer (score 0):

How is 'Item' declared in your code?

The following works fine:

```
Dim item As ListViewItem = ListView1.SelectedItems(0)
ListBox1.Items.Add(item.Text & " " & item.SubItems(1).Text & " " & item.SubItems(2).Text)
```

Comment: whew! I got that. Thanks so much. I'm grateful. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
FOR I=0 TO 10 
Dim item As ListViewItem = ListView1.SelectedItems(0)
ListBox1.Items.Add(item.Text & " " & item.SubItems(1).Text & " " & item.SubItems(2).Text)
NEXT
```